# Is there a way to use Windows system output as JACK input?

Tags: windows, audio

I want to send music played by applications like a webbrowser to a DAW. I thought to use the system master output. I use JACK on Windows, and although it's possible with many applications to connect to JACK via native support or JackRouter, I don't know how to receive the system output as a Jack input.
In this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzd7naKzRgw) video a software called [Synchronous Audio Router](https://github.com/eiz/SynchronousAudioRouter) is used to do this, but I can't find any builds from it and I also wasn't able to build it myself. Are there any other solutions?

Also I am not sure if this is possible using only Jack and no other software. I would be thankful for a hint then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution: It's [VoiceMeter Banana](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm). It creates a virtual audio output device which you can select for the windows system output. From inside the app it is then possible to select JackRouter as audio output. In JackGraph or the JACK Patchbay, VoiceMeter will show up and can be connected to other JACK clients.

Other solutions, especially open source ones, are still welcome though.